# When I inserting AT&T it will add semicolon in code igniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Whenever I was inserting AT&T to database it was added as AT&T; semicolon is added extra in code igniter.

My code is like this:

```
  $this->input->post('carrier_name');
  $this->db->insert('cs_carrier',$insert);
```

please suggest.

Comment: That code doesn't make any sense at all :) Post more.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

replace any special character like & = `&amp;` then you can store into database.Anyway another things.Please make your data field text type otherwise it don't take any special char.

Comment: This doesn't answer the OP's question.

Comment: -1 Don't store HTML entities, encode them for output only (unless it *is* an HTML document you're storing).

Answer (score 0):

In case someone comes across this later. I ran into this issue today, and it turns out it was the `xss_clean` function within CI. I opted not to use it and used `filter_var` instead.